# Get data from Twitter Library search into a struct in Go

Tags: go, twitter, struct

How do I append output from a twitter search to the field Data in the SearchTwitterOutput{} struct.

Thanks!

I am using a twitter library to search twitter base on a query input. The search returns an array of strings(I believe), I am able to fmt.println the data but I need the data as a struct.

```
type SearchTwitterOutput struct {
    Data  string
}

func (SearchTwitter) execute(input SearchTwitterInput) (*SearchTwitterOutput, error) {

    credentials := Credentials{
        AccessToken:       input.AccessToken,
        AccessTokenSecret: input.AccessTokenSecret,
        ConsumerKey:       input.ConsumerKey,
        ConsumerSecret:    input.ConsumerSecret,
    }

    client, err := GetUserClient(&credentials)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // search through the tweet and returns a
    search, _ , err := client.Search.Tweets(&twitter.SearchTweetParams{
        Query: input.Text,
    })
    if err != nil {
        println("PANIC")
        panic(err.Error())
        return &SearchTwitterOutput{}, err
    }

    for k, v := range search.Statuses {
        fmt.Printf("Tweet %d - %s\n", k, v.Text)
    }

    return &SearchTwitterOutput{
        Data: "test", //data is a string for now it can be anything
    }, nil
}

 //Data field is a string type for now it can be anything
//I use "test" as a placeholder, bc IDK...
```

```
Result from fmt.Printf("Tweet %d - %s\n", k, v.Text):
Tweet 0 - You know I had to do it to them! @JennaJulien @Jenna_Marbles @juliensolomita @notjulen Got my first hydroflask ever…
Tweet 1 - RT @brenna_hinshaw: I was in J2 today and watched someone fill their hydroflask with vanilla soft serve... what starts here changes the wor…
Tweet 2 - I miss my hydroflask :(
```

This is my second week working with go and new to development. Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really clear on what you're asking here... You can't append to a struct, but you could append to a slice field of a struct. Appending to slices is covered in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like the client is just returning you a slice of strings. The range syntax you're using (`for k, v := range search.Statuses`) returns two values for each iteration, the index in the slice (in this case `k`), and the object from the slice (in this case `v`). I don't know the type of `search.Statuses` - but I know that strings don't have a `.Text` field or method, which is how you're printing `v` currently.

To your question:

Is there any particular reason to return just a single struct with a `Data` field rather than directly returning the output of the twitter client?

Your function signature could look like this instead:

`func (SearchTwitter) execute(input SearchTwitterInput) ([]<client response struct>, error)`

And then you could operate on the text in those objects in wherever this function was called.

If you're dead-set on placing the data in your own struct, you could return a slice of them (`[]*SearchTwitterOutput`), in which case you could build a single `SearchTwitterOutput` in the for loop you're currently printing the tweets in and append it to the output list. That might look like this:

```
    var output []*SearchTwitterOutput
    for k, v := range search.Statuses {
        fmt.Printf("Tweet %d - %s\n", k, v.Text)
        output = append(output, &SearchTwitterOutput{
            Data: v.Text,
            })
    }

    return output, nil
```

But if your goal really is to return all of the results concatenated together and placed inside a single struct, I would suggest building a slice of strings (containing the text you want), and then joining them with the delimiter of your choosing. Then you could place the single output string in your return object, which might look something like this:

```
    var outputStrings []string
    for k, v := range search.Statuses {
        fmt.Printf("Tweet %d - %s\n", k, v.Text)
        outputStrings = append(outputStrings, v.Text)
    }
    output = strings.Join(outputStrings, ",")

    return &SearchTwitterOutput{
        Data: output,
    }, nil
```

Though I would caution, it might be tricky to find a delimiter that will never show up in a tweet..

Comment: Also, if you're looking for a quick overview of Go's features/structure (and some subtle details like the difference between arrays and slices) - you should check out [the Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/list)!

Comment: Thank you, this brought me down the right path.  I was having issues with the fundamentals ;(. My solution is pretty much what you provided but I changed the Data field to Tweet (string) and Key(int).  YES! Thanks Thanks! I have to send the data via Webhook to Slack.

Comment: No problem. 
Good luck with Go!